# "your changes could not be saved because of a sharing violation"

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have Excel 2013 64bit running a macro that goes through a series of files in my local drive, opens them, refreshes the power queries inside, save and close; this process runs daily, and has worked well since the beginning.

Yesterday one of the files could not be saved, with the message "your changes could not be saved because of a sharing violation", then Excel tries to force me to save with another name. I also cannot delete or cut the file, saying the file is "opened in system".

Since yesterday, this behavior has spread to two more files, rendering them useless. I cannot find a rational explanation nor a solution for this, and this process is critical for my company.

Saving in another directory is also not an option, because those files are mapped as source files for a lot of Tableau reports, and they must be read at their current location and name.

Any help or insight would be great!

Comment: Have you tried to reboot the system?  You should verify the file(s) are not opened on any machine on the network.

Comment: I tried some of this options, I think the PowerQuery addin for Excel 2013 may be the problem - I was even able to save one of the files after disabling the Addin manually.

The thing is, I need this addin to refresh the power queries, so I need to disable the addin programmatically inside the macro before saving, and re-enabling it afterwards... any idea how to accomplish that?

Comment: If you had been using the query without an issue in the past.  You should identify what has changed to cause the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out *what* is keeping the files locked so that they cannot be written to. Either Excel itself (perhaps there is a *second* instance of Excel opened at the same time? Could your application be running in another instance?? Could a previous instance have crashed, leaving the file locked???) or another program, such as an anti-virus application, has opened the file.

There are various ways to monitor a file to check what is accessing it, as has been [answered on StackExchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6702/monitoring-file-access-on-windows). [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/apply-a-basic-audit-policy-on-a-file-or-folder) provides a brief explanation, and [Webspy](https://www.webspy.com/blog/how-to-report-on-who-accessed-a-file-or-folder/) and [Lepide](https://www.lepide.com/how-to/track-who-read-files-on-your-windows-file-servers.html) offer further explanations.

Another useful tool is [LockHunter](https://lockhunter.com/downloadnow.htm), which will tell you what process is locking a file and allow you to unlock it.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac running Catalina (OS X 10.15.4), enabling Full Disk Access in System Preferences/Privacy for each of the Microsoft Office tool (Excel, Powerpoint, Word) seems to resolve the problem. That solution was highlighted on G-Suite support and Microsoft website, but those threads are oddly locked...